# JSF Form with AJAX validation - Focus issues

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, focus, omnifaces

Hi JSF experts out there ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <o:validateOneOrMore components="one two three" id="validate"/>
    <p:message for="validate"/>
    <p:inputText id="one" value="#{testBean.valueOne}">
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="@form"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:inputText id="two" value="#{testBean.valueTwo}">
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="two"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:inputText id="three" value="#{testBean.valueThree}">
        <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" update="one two validate"/>
    </p:inputText>
    <p:commandButton process="@form"
                     update="@form"
                     value="Submit"
                     partialSubmit="true"
                     action="#{testBean.submit}"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

a simple form with requirement of at least one form filled, immediate error reset and tab-able.

But i didn't get it work, tried different things as you can see in sample code.

What happens

- hit submit -> error message shown: fine
- enter entry in field one and leave with tab: fine (all fields are not in error state anymore and message is gone) BUT focus lost after complete AJAX update. Ok expected behavior of JSF and browsers as i read here, but how to solve?
- delete all entries, hit enter -> input in field three and leave the field ... nothing changes ... even message is not gone sth. i also do not understand, since i updated all fields

Is there any solution out, for having a form like that ... where after each input validation of form will happen (meaning remove such global errors) and still have it quickly usable by using the tab-key?

thx.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here, but surely it's bad practice to update the managed bean via ajax when input changes. Better to forget about that and perform the validation only when form is submited using the button. Like that you'll get a quick tab perfomance.

Comment: ha sure ... but if i now enter sth. into the fields i want to remove the errors, since it is not clear to the user saying to fill at least one field, and after he is filling in sth. into one, error is still displayed. The <p:ajax> is basically not to update managed bean, but to immediatley update validation state.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying issue, which has to do with the way JSF preforms partial renders, there is an in depth post regarding [JSF 2 AJAX focus issues](http://www.knitelius.com/2014/07/15/keeping-focus-on-element-with-jsf-2-ajax-render/).

Which offers a potential solution in the form of using the JSF JavaScript API to listen for triggered AJAX request and refocusing, have a look at the post for further details.